# How to save a PDF stream in IE9 using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, blob

I want to download binary files using Javascript.

I have a REST service that returns the binary data and i want to know how save the binary file as pdf in IE9 using FileSaver.js or any other method.

This is my current code, it's work for IE10 and IE11 but not in IE9:

```
if(IEFactory.ie()){
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(new Blob([data], {type:"application/pdf"}), "rapport.pdf");
}
```

i'm using FileSaver.js and Blob.js

Any idea how can i make it work for IE9, Thank you.

Comment: Blob and File APIs are not available for IE9, so you can not do this.

Comment: There is any other API can do this ?

Comment: Hi, @user3383054, did you solve this? Facing a similar problem.

Comment: @Lucho Any other options?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way around this on the front-end layer. May be you can serve the pdf content as a separate file with header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` - this will pop-up a dialog to save the file.